# Publish multiple instances of endpoints on the same address

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have to simulate 3 servers working on the same machine.

We can say that there are three instances of server namely: 
`Vikings`, `Falcons` and `Raiders`

Now, I would like to publish 3 instances of the same endpoint:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/team-server", new Team("Falcons")); 
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/team-server", new Team("Vikings")); 
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/team-server", new Team("Raiders"));
```

However, I am not able to do so. I know I can use different address to publish 3 different instances but I am not allowed to do so.

Please note, that server and clients exists on the same machine. That's why I need three instances of the server as there are 3 teams.

Thanks!!

Comment: When you enter `http://localhost:8081/team-server` into the browser on that machine, to which should it go?

Comment: Well, I am not sure, I had used 3 different address for 3 instances of team. However, I was told to use only one address. That's why i am wondering what to do!! Thanks!!

Comment: :) It's not possible to have different things come up when the address is identical. You have to change a thing in the address. Like the port number, the path, or even the ip (difficult but doable via virtual network interfaces or vhosts and a service like xip.io https://viget.com/extend/device-testing-local-virtual-hosts ) - maybe you should ask the one that said you must use the same address how it's supposed to work

Comment: Actually, it is an assignment, I did it using 3 address. But the Teaching Assistant asked me to do using one address. So, technically speaking 3 address is the correct way, right? I will so him your answer on stackoverflow. Thanks!!

Comment: I kind of doubt the teaching assistant meant using absolutely identical addresses for different things at the same time. But I also don't know what the intended goal was. Maybe to do a single `Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/team-server", new AllTheTeams());` that handles everything somehow dynamically?

Comment: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/multiplexed-endpointreferences.html is roughly an automatic AllTheTeams endpoint that